# Отображение reCaptcha Android на web сайте?

Tags: php, android, recaptcha

Есть приложение на андроиде к примеру myapp.apk и там используется reCaptcha Android(В качестве проверки при создании данной капчи на сайте гугла необходимо вписать название библиотек которые будут проверяться), приложение работает соответственно на Java.

Мне необходимо сделать отображение данной reCaptch`и на своем web сайте, что бы посетители моего сайта могли разгадывать данную капчу.

Comment: Необходимо - делайте. Тут только помогают в реализации.

Comment: Мне бы хотя бы совет в каком направлении двигаться, такого вроде не кто не делал ещё.